# view value of variables in a completion function

Tags: zsh

I have [found](https://askql.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/zsh-writing-own-completion/) the following zsh completion function

```
#compdef _h h

_h() { 
    local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
 
    _arguments \
        '1: :->country'\
        '*: :->city'
 
    case $state in
    country)
        _arguments '1:Countries:(France Germany Italy)'
    ;;
    *)
        case $words[2] in
        France)
            compadd "$@" Paris Lyon Marseille
        ;;
        Germany)
            compadd "$@" Berlin Munich Dresden
        ;;
        Italy)
            compadd "$@" Rome Napoli Palermo
        ;;
        *)
            _files 
        esac
    esac
}
```

I want to see (`echo`) the value of the variables (`$curcontext`,`$state`,`$line` and `$words`) but not sure where or how the output will be shown (as completion function is only triggered when I press <kbd>tab</kbd>).

How can I see the value of the variables mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. I also asked the question in [zsh-users GitHub page](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/issues/759). The answer with with some extras is given below.

Put the following line in your completion file.

```
echo "curcontext=$curcontext state=$state line=$line words=$words[@]"
```

If you want to print the debug output in another terminal then use:

```
echo "curcontext=$curcontext state=$state line=$line words=$words[@]" > device_file_path # like /dev/pts/3
```

Type `tty` in the terminal where you want to see the debug output to get its `device_file_path`.